# On perspective change from Web to java i can't open .xml file in editor for Eclipse Plugin Project

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, perspective, perspectives

I have a eclipse plugin project, in this project i have to change perspective java to web and web to java. at the time web to java accordingly, i want to open this file in editor directly. For .java file i have no issue to open by this code,

```
openEditor(projectFile,"org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor",page, filePath);
```

But when i want to open .xml, maximum time i was failed to open this file and got message "this file does not exist in path", but file has present already.

So, is there is any need or reference for change .xml file "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor" on this command. please help. Advance Thanks.

Comment: `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor` only opens Java source and class files. You need to use some other editor for XML.

Comment: ok,thanks for your reply. can you suggest which unitEditor require for .xml file

Comment: You should generally not specify an editor id when opening a file, let Eclipse work out the best editor to use.

Comment: In past, I have used this code for open editor id   editorID = workbench.getEditorRegistry().getDefaultEditor(file.getFullPath().toString()).getId(); but every time get exception worksapce is closed for that i am getting ID null all time. thats the reason i have used specific ID. those all thinks happen after export a jar and that jar used on another platform like eclipse.

Comment: If you have better suggession to recover this issue please help.